# PayPal won't automatically redirect to my site after payment complete

Tags: paypal

For some reason PayPal won't redirect to my site after a payment is confirmed.

I have set auto return and set a valid url.

I have set a hidden param of return to the same url.

It just shows me a payment complete page with a link back to my site (the same url as above). If i click this then it takes me back to my site - hence I know the url is valid.

I just want this to happen automatically, which is what is supposed to happen if I set these options is it not?

Why is paypal so cumbersome? Or am I missing the blindingly obvious?

I'm using paypal standard with a business account.

Comment: I believe you can not do this automatically with Paypal Payments Standard (which I assume you are using).

Comment: @BrunoSilva You CAN do this automatically using PayPal Payments Standard (I've done it).  PayPal should automatically redirect to the return url, after displaying their own payment completion page for a few seconds (you can't get rid of this page).  Auto-return must be turned on as detailed [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside). If I remember right, if the user pays with a credit or debit card, and doesn't log into PayPal it won't work.  It only works if the user logs into their PayPal account.

Comment: @AlexSchimp You are right, thanks for providing a lot more detail than what I had in my original response. I also have it on my own websites but the PayPal completion page shows up (even if temporarily).

Comment: Alex is correct. I am not logging in so this seems to be the reason that it doesn't work! Poor show PayPal

Answer (score 0):

Go to profile [website preference page](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments) and turn on the auto return option.

Edit:
In addition to the answer posted above, to turn on the auto return option, follow the below links:

- Click on Profile underneath the My Account Tab
- Click on *My Selling Tools* on the left hand side
  Select the update option next to

> Website preferencesReturn customers to my website after they pay with PayPal.

- Locate the option to turn on Auto Return and proceed accordingly.

*N.B. Over the past weeks trying to implement PayPal, I have come to understand that Paypal have a very confusing website and documentation and very often you may find contradicting things. So please note that the set of links above may change at a moment's notice. - DottoreM*

Comment: I have added the steps for the sake of clarity. I repeat to what I have already written above. the steps outlined may only be correct now and change soon, PayPal is an extremely confusing site.

Comment: OP already stated two years previously that he has done all these things.

Answer (score 0):

From @AlexSchimp's comment above:

> If the user pays with a credit or debit card, and doesn't log into PayPal it won't work. It only works if the user logs into their PayPal account.

Answer (score 0):

The "Website payment preference" auto return URL functionality will only work for the payments processed via "WPS (Website Payments Standard)" i,e PayPal HTML button integration payments.

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/returnurl" />
```

**OR**

Check this URL:

https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside.

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks

Poonam (http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in)

Comment: OP already stated four years previously that he has done all these things.